# Restore postgres data from remote machine using PITR

Tags: postgresql-9.1, restore

I am doing backup-restore using Continuous Archiving and Point-In-Time Recovery (PITR).

I am able to do it on my machine. But when I try to restore data (WAL files) from remote machine it doesn't work as expected.

I am specifying WAL files location (remote location) for 'restore_command' in recovery.conf file.

I guess the issue could be that user who is responsible for doing restore is not having aceess to that folder.

Has anybody done resore WAL files from other machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me with the following setting

```
restore_command = ' scp pg_user@remote_server_ip:/where/wal/backup/is/%f %p'
recovery_target_time = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
recovery_target_inclusive ='true'
```

Make sure pg_user owns the wal backup files.
Make sure postgres user owns the recovery.conf and the file is both readable and writable.

```
As root$ chmod 600 recovery.conf
As root$ chown postgres:postgres recovery.conf
```

I hope this helps.
You will have more specific help if you post the server log here.